# SQL Stored Procedure not handling error from nested stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures, one nested inside the other.  When the nested stored procedure is called, at the moment, it should error with a foreign key constraint violation and then rollback the earlier call to insert into the ProductLicense table.  The nested procedure does not perform any action on the database because of the foreign key violation but the calling stored procedure isn't catching the error and rolling back.  If I execute the nested stored procedure by itself it does return error 547 Foreign key violation.

How can I get the two stored procedures to work together?

Outer procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNewLicense2_i]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @customerId nvarchar(10),
    @licenseModeId int,
    @licenseModeProgramId int,
    @createdBy int,
    @updateBy int,
    @systemId nvarchar(50),
    @productId int

AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        --SET XACT_ABORT ON;  --used for automatic rollback when an error occurs    

        DECLARE @tempDays INT
        DECLARE @programCornerAmt INT
        DECLARE @tempEndDate DATETIME
        DECLARE @tempExpDate DATETIME
        DECLARE @err INT

        SET @err = 0

        /*SET @tempDays = (SELECT lmp.TimeoutDays
                         FROM LicenseModeProgram lmp 
                         WHERE lmp.LicenseModeProgramId = @licenseModeProgramId)*/

        SELECT @tempDays = TimeoutDays, @programCornerAmt = MonthlyCornersAmount
        FROM LicenseModeProgram
        WHERE LicenseModeProgramId = @licenseModeProgramId

        --Build Expiration and End Dates.
        IF @tempDays = NULL --then this is NOT a time rental or metered system
            BEGIN
                SET @tempEndDate = NULL
                SET @tempExpDate = NULL
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @tempEndDate = DATEADD("d", @tempDays, GETDATE())
                SET @tempExpDate = DATEADD("d", @tempDays, GETDATE())
            END 

        -- Create new product license record
        INSERT INTO ProductLicense (CustomerId, LicenseModeId, LicenseModeProgramId, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, SystemId, ProductId, ExpirationDate, LicenseEndDate)
        VALUES (@customerId, @licenseModeId, @licenseModeProgramId, @createdBy, @updateBy, @systemId, @productId, @tempExpDate, @tempEndDate)

        IF @licenseModeId = 4 AND @systemId  NULL AND @programCornerAmt  NULL
            --call stored procedure to add corners to the customer account
            EXECUTE @err = AddMeteredTx_i @systemId, 1, 1, @programCornerAmt , 'Initial License Creation'

        PRINT @err

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    RAISERROR('Failed to Create License', 11, 2)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RETURN 1
END CATCH

    --COMMIT TRANSACTION
RETURN 0
GO
```

Inner procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddMeteredTx_i]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @systemId nvarchar(50),
    @activityEventId int,
    @createdBy int,
    @amount int,
    @notes text
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        --SET XACT_ABORT ON;  --used for automatic rollback when an error occurs

        INSERT INTO CustomerAccountActivity (SystemId, ActivityEventId, CreatedBy, Amount, Notes)
        VALUES (@systemId, @activityEventId, @createdBy, @amount, @notes)

        UPDATE CustomerAccount
        SET MeteredBalance = (SELECT MeteredBalance FROM CustomerAccount WHERE SystemId = @systemId) + @amount
        WHERE SystemId = @systemId

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    RAISERROR('Error Update to Customer Account Record ', 11, 2)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RETURN 1

    --COMMIT TRANSACTION
END CATCH

RETURN 0
GO
```

Comment: We need to see the code for the outer procedure too.

Comment: Also, please avoid using `@@ERROR` to detect errors, `TRY/CATCH` is a lot more robust.

Comment: Sorry about that,  I just added it.

Answer (score 6):

Catching errors with a call stack like this using `@@Error` can be problematic. It's a lot more reliable to use [`TRY/CATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

The basic format is:

```
BEGIN TRY
<BEGIN TRAN>

... do stuff ...
<COMMIT TRAN>
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
<ROLLBACK TRAN>
... do error stuff like re-raise the error to outer scope ...


END CATCH
```

Any error encountered in the try will automatically take you to the CATCH block without additional checking.

Comment: so you are suggesting the reason the foreign constraint violation isn't being raised is because I am not using try/catch blocks?

Comment: Yes, possibly. The last command to execute before the error is actually a ROLLBACK. `@@ERROR` is very very unreliable. Even MS says not to use it.

Comment: I updated the stored procedures as you suggested and still the error is not caught.

Comment: In the inner proc, as soon as you re-raise the error it escalates to the catch in the outer scope. Try reordering your process there.

Comment: Still no difference.  When I run the inner procedure as a single execute stored procedure the error is returned to the result window.  Why is it not being returned to the calling procedure.  That is why I have the declared @err just to catch the return value to see if it will work.

Comment: I believe I resolved the issue and am embarrassed to say that my conditional branch before the call to the nested stored proc was incorrectly written.  instead of testing for not null with <> I should have written it as IS NOT NULL.  I was getting my languages mixed up.  Thank you for the assistance and trying to help.

Comment: Not sure the protocol for flagging this message now that the issue is resolved?